# Insert Selected data in database

Tags: php, mysql, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Basically I want to insert a Foreign key acc_id in patient_info table from account_info table.

I have managed to retrieve the data from my database. Now I want to insert it in another table as Foreign key. I have following code :

```
 try {
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1');
        while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            // Assign each row of data to associative array
                $data[] = $row;
        }

        // Return data as JSON
            echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

How can I insert the value in the table?
this is the full code :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

 // Define database connection parameters
 $hn      = 'localhost';
 $un      = 'root';
 $pwd     = '';
 $db      = 'ringabell';
 $cs      = 'utf8';

 // Set up the PDO parameters
 $dsn  = "mysql:host=" . $hn . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $cs;
 $opt  = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                   );
// Create a PDO instance (connect to the database)
$pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);

 // Retrieve specific parameter from supplied URL
 $key  = strip_tags($_REQUEST['key']);
$data = array();

 switch($key)

{
   // Add a new record to the technologies table
  case "create":

     // Sanitise URL supplied value
     $acc_id                = filter_var($_REQUEST['acc_id'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_fname               = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_fname'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_lname               = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_lname'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_gender              = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_gender'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_condition           = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_condition'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_emergencycontact    = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_emergencycontact'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_birthdate           = filter_var($_REQUEST['p_birthdate'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW); 

try{

    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1');
    while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            // Assign each row of data to associative array
                $data[] = $row;
        }

        // Return data as JSON
            echo json_encode($data); 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO patient_info(acc_id, p_fname, p_lname, p_gender, p_condition, p_birthdate, p_emergencycontact)    
                            VALUES(:acc_id, :p_fname, :p_lname, :p_gender, :p_condition, :p_birthdate, :p_emergencycontact)";


        $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

        $stmt->bindParam(':p_fname', $p_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_lname', $p_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_gender', $p_gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_condition', $p_condition, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_birthdate', $p_birthdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_emergencycontact', $p_emergencycontact, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':acc_id', $acc_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 


        $stmt->execute();

         echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record was added to the database')); 

}
     // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }

 break;
}
?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I am getting the error here which links back to the php file:

```
load()
{
  this.http.get('http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data =>
  {
     this.items = data;
  });
}
```

---

Solution: [insert slected data as Foreign key and SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663845/insert-slected-data-as-foreign-key-and-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-vio)

Comment: And what exactly issue you are facing doing this ?

Comment: i can  return the value selected but when ever i add the rest of the code i get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: You are posting php code with a javascript error. Post the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Notsure, but try using ` PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` in your fetch.

Comment: @NigelRen i still get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could improve your code by removing your while loop and instead go like :

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Are you sure you're getting expected JSON (tried any var_dump of $data before printing it ?) ?
Isn't it just a simple problem with JavaScript ? Have you tried to use the data you're supposed to get in your JavaScript part ?

It might be a problem of setting headers inside your XMLHttpRequest, and JavaScript doesn't care and give you the JSON anyway...

Now obvious questions :

- I can't see where you connect to your database. Are you connected ?
- You're trying to insert an ID, does MySQL allow you to INSERT auto increment value ? (in which case, isn't acc_id an Int ?)
- You're sending values through $_REQUEST, are you sure you're getting anything through $_REQUEST (btw, check $_GET and $_POST)

I hope it helps

Comment: Hello! thank you for helping me ! I improved my code like you suggested, however i can't test it still getting the error. Now, it is connected . and yes it is auto increment, the values in the other table worked perfectly. Is there a way to retrieve and add a Foreign key other than the one i'm using maybe better ??

Comment: What's in this page ?    
[http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php](http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php)  
If id is an auto increment value, remove it from your INSERT action

Comment: maybe i wan't clear in my question ac_id is auto increment in account_info table. I want to insert it in patient_info table as a link between the 2 tables as a foreign key

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake... And what is $key on which you switch ? Are you sure it's filled ?  
Have you looked at your database if the lines were inserted ? What do you have in $_REQUEST ?

Comment: in $key i had the options to create update or delete. The account-info table is filled correctly. nothing in Request but code won't work without it

Comment: Ok... It's probably because of my pity english but I don't get the problem then... If you don't have anything in your $_REQUEST, it might be why you can't INSERT anything into your table ? Maybe your data are simply stocked into $_GET. If it's a MySQL error, you'd be able to detect it running something like
`if ($stmt->errorCode() !== '00000') {
            die($stmt->errorInfo()[2]);
/*or just 'echo json_encode($stmt->errorInfo());'*/
        } else {
            echo json_encode($data);`
You could also put your code in the load function inside a promise to see if you get something then

Comment: the error is on `.map(res => res.json())` , `var_dump($data)` returns `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["acc_id"]=> int(124) } }`